# My gridView is not showing on the mainactivity

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, baseadapter

I have a gridView adapter here :

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.inflate
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

class ImageAdapter constructor(private val mContext: Context, private val images: Array<Int>) :  BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var convertView = convertView

        if(convertView == null) {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, null)
        }
        val image = convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.added_picture)
        image.setImageResource(images[position])

        return convertView
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

I am trying to set the cardView on every cell of the gridView, here is my card_view.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="110dp"
  android:layout_height="110dp"
  android:layout_margin="3dp"
  app:layout_columnSpan="1"
  app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
  app:layout_rowSpan="1"
  app:layout_column="2"
  app:layout_row="0" >
  <ImageView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/added_picture"
    />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I am trying to call the adapter like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var initialGridPosition = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        gridView.adapter = ImageAdapter(this, arrayOf(R.drawable.filled_rectangle, R.drawable.filled_rectangle))
     }
}
```

This is the gridView in my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
    android:paddingVertical="30dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <GridView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:numColumns="3"
      android:id="@+id/gridView"
      />
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It is not showing me the gridView while I'm the app, but in the mainActivity gridView.adapter is not null after assigning it to the ImageAdapter object.

Comment: dont inherit from `BaseAdapter` instead you should inherit from `RecyclerView.Adapter<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is  getcount() method returns always 0 so you have return images size in it.

```
override fun getCount(): Int {
        return images.size
 }
```

Comment: Now after adding glide        Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.filled_rectangle).into(image) after initializing image in the adapter, the gridView is coming blank